# Why does 12/2 = 7?

Tags: mathematics, lateral-thinking

Here's a quickie while I work on the fourth floor of the Puzzle Dungeon. It's going to be here within the next two days, probably.

Find a way to divide 12 by 2 so you get 7. There are several rules:

> 1. No base systems or modular arithmetic.
> 2. No adding anything to the equation (lines, greater than signs, etc.)

I think that's it. Good Luck!

Comment: @Hugh yes it is, I VTC.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Twelve in roman numerals is XII, "cut in half" horizontally is VII — seven.